# Count numbers in single row - SQL

Tags: sql

is it possible to return count of values in single row?
For example this is test table and I want to count of daily_typing_pages

```
SQL> SELECT * FROM employee_tbl;
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
| id   | name | work_date  | daily_typing_pages |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
|    1 | John | 2007-01-24 |                250 |
|    2 | Ram  | 2007-05-27 |                220 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-05-06 |                170 |
|    3 | Jack | 2007-04-06 |                100 |
|    4 | Jill | 2007-04-06 |                220 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-06-06 |                300 |
|    5 | Zara | 2007-02-06 |                350 |
+------+------+------------+--------------------+
```

Result of this count should be : 1610 how ever if I simply count() AROUND it return:

```
SQL>SELECT COUNT(daily_typing_pages) FROM employee_tbl ;

+---------------------------+
| COUNT(daily_typing_pages) |
+---------------------------+
|             7             |
+---------------------------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

So it return number of rows instead of count single row.
Is there some way how to do things like I want without using external programming language which will count it for me?

Thanks

Comment: You mean `SUM(daily_typing_pages)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `SUM` instead of `COUNT`. `COUNT` merely counts the number of records, you want them summed.

You didn't mention your DBMS, but see for example, for sql server [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

Comment: If this is the answer you wanted, pls flag it as answer!

Comment: just did it, was waiting for time approval

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean you want to summarize alle numbers of daily_typing_pages ?

So you can use `sum(daily_typing_pages)`:

```
SELECT SUM(daily_typing_pages) FROM employee_tbl
```